# Countdown that can mix various times

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Does anyone know about a countdown that can mix various times and display them one after another?

What I need is a countdown for every hour of the working day (8:00 AM -> 9:00 AM -> 10:00 AM -> ... -> 5:00 PM) then the same counter should turn into a countdown from 5:00 PM to 8:00 AM.

Is it possible with javascript, php? If yes, does anyone know where can I see an example?

Comment: You question is very unclear.

Comment: "a countdown for every hour of the working day (8:00 AM -> 9:00 AM -> 10:00 AM -> ... -> 5:00 PM) then the same counter should turn into a countdown from 5:00 PM to 8:00 AM." Why is this unclear? How can I make it clearer than this?

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. Is it possible? Yes it is.

Comment: At least this is an answer, I can start from here.

The questions: "Does anyone know about a countdown that can mix various times and display them one after another? Is it possible with javascript, php? If yes, does anyone know where can I see an example?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
https://jsfiddle.net/6bd3L1ew/7/

```
config = {
'0':8,
'1':7,
'2':6,
'3':5,
'4':4,
'5':3,
'6':2,
'7':1,
'8':1,
'9':1,
'10':1,
'11':1,
'12':1,
'13':1,
'14':1,
'15':1,
'16':1,
'17':15,
'18':14,
'19':13,
'20':12,
'21':11,
'22':10,
'23':9
}

var start = new Date();

function pad(num) {
  return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
}

function tick() {

  var nowTime = new Date().getHours();
  var untilTime = new Date().getHours() + config[nowTime]

  start.setHours(untilTime, 0, 0);

  var now = new Date();
  if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
  }
  var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
  var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
  var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
  var ss = pad(remain % 60);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =
    hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
  setTimeout(tick, 1000);
}

tick();
```

Comment: Thank you @Rashomon! That's exactly what I needed. https://i.imgur.com/YFtgP59.png

And this part of the comment is for those who downvoted my question: @Rashomon 's attitude is the attitude that I needed, not an "all-knowing" reply.

Comment: Make sure its working well. I think now it got crazy at this time... Maybe this (https://jsfiddle.net/6bd3L1ew/10/) Problem is that I cannot test easily what happens when time its exactly the interval between two hours (12:59 to 13:00 for example)

Comment: Thank you. I'll check if it acts like it should at the minute between the hours.